# What is the name of that motion where one repeatedly bows to another with arms outstretched?

Tags: single-word-requests

What I'm thinking of is usually not performed as a very deep bow as the torso doesn't really move far from the vertical.  And when it's done, it's often performed in rapid succession, with kind of a facetious manner. The intended meaning is to pay homage, to say "I am in awe [of what you just did]."  Does a specific word describing this motion exist?

Comment: When you say _arms outstretched_ do you mean out to the side or out in front in a prayer-like formation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe might be a self-conscious or theatrical "salaam", an Islamic salutation properly executed as a low bow while pressing the palm of one's right hand to the forehead.

Comment: And, IIRC, with the left hand extending forward.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of [kowtowing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kowtow), maybe? Traditionally, that involves kneeling and touching your forehead to the ground, but people sometimes use it more loosely (and facetiously).

Comment: It's not so much that it's used *more loosely* (as in, *might be applied to various submissive body posturing*). It's just much more likely to be used *figuratively*. Disregarding the actual meaning, "Blair kowtowed to Bush over Iraq" sounds much more acceptable than "Blair salaamed to Bush..."

Comment: No, _kowtow_ is a good word, but it isn't what I'm thinking of.  I think of someone who is kowtowing as someone clearly demonstrating lower status or supplication, which is not the case for this gesture -- one might do it to an equal, who's done something great to deserve it.  The motion I'm thinking of is not so deep as a kowtow or a genuflection.

Answer (score 1):

"Worshipping" is the best word I could use to describe it

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a reference to a 'Hail Mary'... especially if used in a facetious manner.  Islam also has a similar movement with a different word.